# $G=\{A\in M_2(\mathbb C) \mid |\det(A)|=1\}$ and $H=\{A\in M_2(\mathbb C)\mid \det(A)=1\}$ are not isomomorphic

Tags: matrices, group-theory

Can somebody give me some tips how to prove that the groups $G=\{A\in M_2(\mathbb C)\mid |\det(A)|=1\}$ and $H=\{A\in M_2(\mathbb C)\mid \det(A)=1\}$ are not isomomorphic , please?

Comment: Look at their centres?

Comment: Their centers are equal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** See how many elements each group has whose square is the identity element.